# Recursive BCP import won't work in a batch file

Tags: sql-server, batch-file, cmd, sql-server-2012

I'm importing a set of data files in a folder into a SQL Server table.  I'm able to run a recursive `bcp` if I enter it manually on the command line, but it doesn't work if I put it in a batch file.

The command is:

```
for /r %i in (*) do bcp databasename.dbo.tablename in %i -c  -t -S servername -U username -P password -t "|"
```

The error returned is `-c was unexpected at this time`.  If I remove the `-c` I get `-t was unexpected at this time`, and so on.

Comment: Just to be sure there aren't any errors, could you redirect the output of the bcp command to a file?

Comment: @TT. I've added the output of the bcp command to the Q

Comment: Try put the second  `%i` between double quotes like `"%i"`. Also you have `-t` specified twice in your command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the filenames ended up with space and dash characters when loaded to %i and these were interpreted as meaningful parts of the `bcp` command, which of course screwed it up.  The simple but annoying solution is to make sure the directory names and filenames don't have spaces or dashes.